# How to control bitrate (by time) of MP3 - different CBR/VBR in different sections?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I have a audio file several hours in length which is 85% talking, and 15% music. I want the talking to have a VBR ~64 kbps - and the music to be 256 kbps. Setting just 1 VBR across the file doesn't work so well, I'd rather do it manually and say "I want these parts to have this bitrate, and these others to have a different one". Is this possible? And if not with mp3, with another format?